# ImageView in List will not clear previous image

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have `ListView` that accepts an `ArrayAdapter`. The `ArrayAdapter` has an `ImageView` that is populated by Picasso (the library from Square) when an image is shared. However, after a message with an image is shared and placed in the `ImageView` in that list item, if another message, without an image, is shared, that same previous image is populated into the `ImageView`, instead of being blank, as it should be if no image is shared.

I have researched and attempted to set that `ImageView` to null or transparent if there is no image being shared but nothing works. Thus far I have tried:

`sharedSpecial.setImageBitmap(null);` and `sharedSpecial.setImageResource(0);` but neither work.

How can I "clear" the `ImageView` from showing the previous image in the `ListView` if no present image is shared?

The `ArrayAdapter` class for setting the image given the type of sharing is below:

```
public class DiscussArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OneComment> {

private TextView countryName;
private ImageView sharedSpecial;

private MapView locationMap;
private GoogleMap map;

private List<OneComment> countries = new ArrayList<OneComment>();
private LinearLayout wrapper;


String getSharedSpecialURL = null;
String getSharedSpecialWithLocationURL = null;

String specialsActionURL = "http://" + Global.getIpAddress()
        + ":3000/getSharedSpecial/";

String specialsLocationActionURL = "http://" + Global.getIpAddress()
        + ":3000/getSharedSpecialWithLocation/";

String JSON = ".json";

@Override
public void add(OneComment object) {
    countries.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

public DiscussArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.countries.size();
}

public OneComment getItem(int index) {
    return this.countries.get(index);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

    OneComment comment = getItem(position);

    countryName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);

    sharedSpecial = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sharedSpecial);

    countryName.setText(comment.comment);

    // Initiating Volley
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();

    // Check if message has campaign or campaign/location attached
    if (comment.campaign_id == "0" && comment.location_id == "0") {

        sharedSpecial.setImageBitmap(null);

    } else if (comment.campaign_id != "0" && comment.location_id != "0") {

        // If both were shared
        getSharedSpecialWithLocationURL = specialsLocationActionURL + comment.campaign_id + "/" + comment.location_id + JSON;


        // GET JSON data and parse
        JsonObjectRequest getCampaignLocationData = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getSharedSpecialWithLocationURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        // Parse the JSON:
                        try {
                            resultObject = response.getJSONObject("shared");

                            imageObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("image");
                            adImageURL = imageObject.getString("url");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Get and set image
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://" + Global.getIpAddress() + ":3000" + adImageURL).into(sharedSpecial);
                        sharedSpecial.setImageResource(0);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        requestQueue.add(getCampaignLocationData);


    } else if (comment.campaign_id != "0" && comment.location_id == "0") {

        // Just the campaign is shared
        getSharedSpecialURL = specialsActionURL + comment.campaign_id + JSON;

        // Test Campaign id = 41

        // GET JSON data and parse

        JsonObjectRequest getCampaignData = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getSharedSpecialURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        // Parse the JSON:
                        try {
                            resultObject = response.getJSONObject("shared");

                            imageObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("image");
                            adImageURL = imageObject.getString("url");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Get and set image
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://" + Global.getIpAddress() + ":3000" + adImageURL).into(sharedSpecial);
                        sharedSpecial.setImageResource(0);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        requestQueue.add(getCampaignData);

        // Location set to empty
    }

    // If left is true, then yello, if not then set to green bubble
    countryName.setBackgroundResource(comment.left ? R.drawable.bubble_yellow : R.drawable.bubble_green);
    wrapper.setGravity(comment.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);

    return row;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your getView method. You are not attaching the inflated xml to the row. You are declaring the components (textview etc) globally while it is best to create a holder class which can then be attached.

Can you please try the following for your adapter :

**UPDATE**
Added constructor taking the list as a paramter. Now you call the adapter like so :

```
DiscussArrayAdapter adapter = new DiscussArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.message_list_item, countries);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then its important to trust the adapter **notifyDataSetChanged**.

In the activity create the countries list and the adapter globally and whenever you add / remove items from the list just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

**Adapter:**

```
public class DiscussArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OneComment>{


private MapView locationMap;
private GoogleMap map;

private List<OneComment> countries;

public DiscussArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<OneComment> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.countries = objects;
}
String getSharedSpecialURL = null;
String getSharedSpecialWithLocationURL = null;

String specialsActionURL = "http://" + Global.getIpAddress()
        + ":3000/getSharedSpecial/";

String specialsLocationActionURL = "http://" + Global.getIpAddress()
        + ":3000/getSharedSpecialWithLocation/";

String JSON = ".json";

@Override
public void add(OneComment object) {
    countries.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

public DiscussArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.countries.size();
}

public OneComment getItem(int index) {
    return this.countries.get(index);
}

public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {

     //Create instance of inflated view holder
    Holder holder;

    if (row == null) {

        //Its the first time we are going to inflate the view, get new instance of Holder            
        holder = new Holder();

        //Inflate view
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_item, parent, false);

        //Put components in the holder
        holder.countryName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        holder.sharedSpecial = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sharedSpecial);
        holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

        //Attach holder to the row
        row.setTag(holder);

    }else{

        //Row was inflated before get holder 
        holder = (Holder)row.getTag();
    }



    OneComment comment = getItem(position);
    countryName.setText(comment.comment);

    // Initiating Volley
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();

    // Check if message has campaign or campaign/location attached
    if (comment.campaign_id.equals("0") && comment.location_id.equals("0")) {

        sharedSpecial.setImageBitmap(null);

    } else if (!comment.campaign_id.equals("0") && !comment.location_id.equals("0")) {

        // If both were shared
        getSharedSpecialWithLocationURL = specialsLocationActionURL + comment.campaign_id + "/" + comment.location_id + JSON;


        // GET JSON data and parse
        JsonObjectRequest getCampaignLocationData = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getSharedSpecialWithLocationURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        // Parse the JSON:
                        try {
                            resultObject = response.getJSONObject("shared");

                            imageObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("image");
                            adImageURL = imageObject.getString("url");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Get and set image
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://" + Global.getIpAddress() + ":3000" + adImageURL).into(sharedSpecial);
                        sharedSpecial.setImageResource(0);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        requestQueue.add(getCampaignLocationData);


    } else if (!comment.campaign_id.equals("0") && comment.location_id.equals("0")) {

        // Just the campaign is shared
        getSharedSpecialURL = specialsActionURL + comment.campaign_id + JSON;

        // Test Campaign id = 41

        // GET JSON data and parse

        JsonObjectRequest getCampaignData = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getSharedSpecialURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        // Parse the JSON:
                        try {
                            resultObject = response.getJSONObject("shared");

                            imageObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("image");
                            adImageURL = imageObject.getString("url");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Get and set image
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://" + Global.getIpAddress() + ":3000" + adImageURL).into(sharedSpecial);
                        sharedSpecial.setImageResource(0);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        requestQueue.add(getCampaignData);

        // Location set to empty
    }

    // If left is true, then yello, if not then set to green bubble
    countryName.setBackgroundResource(comment.left ? R.drawable.bubble_yellow : R.drawable.bubble_green);
    wrapper.setGravity(comment.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);

    return row;
}

private class Holder{
    TextView countryName;
    ImageView sharedSpecial;
    LinearLayout wrapper;
}

}
```

Comment: Do I call notify dataset changed before or after I add new items?

Comment: This did not work. The images still fall through to the next message, or inherit the image from another message

Comment: I got this to run, but even with notifyDataSetCahnge(), the previous image still populates those Null ImageViews, how can I get around that?

Comment: hi..you can have a standard image to load for null images..like the default if there is no image..or else set the image resource to null if there is no image to load

Comment: I have used the setImageResource(0) and setImageResource(null), and both times they did not prevent the other images from being loaded

Comment: It ended up being the "==" was comparing two string objects so it was always true on all occasions, thus the else if being true. You did help, you can change your answer to include and it will be correct as well

Comment: Sry I didn't follow that part of the code as I should have..glad its working for u

Comment: You can edit and update your answer if you want, just for solid record keeping

Comment: was the error in thjis line? comment.campaign_id != "0" && comment.location_id == "0"